# Read what is typed in life time on JTextField and also JLabel refresh in the same time

Tags: java

Hey i made a program where you type your nickname and this nickname is taken to read Image from url. Is there any way to make it when i for example type in my JTextField nickname "jeb_" it will refresh and change JLabel in the same time to load new image before pressing button to do it ?

Comment: Just add a listener to the textfield so that it tracks when the text changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to make it when i for example type in my JTextField nickname "jeb_" it will refresh and change JLabel in the same time

You add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of your `JTextField`. An event will be generated every time you add (or remove) a character.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Listener For Changes on a Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more information and a working example to get you started.